# Start activity using intent with extra does not show all the extras

Tags: android, android-intent, extras

Inside a setOnItemClickListener I use an intent to start a new activity. I put 7 strings as extras for this intent. When I click an item (of a ListView) I want all these extras to be displayed (on a new screen). But I see only the first 4 extras. Here's the layout file for the new activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address_entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28dip" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/city_entry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="28dip" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/zip_entry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="28dip" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/state_entry"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="28dip" />
    </LinearLayout>    

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28dip" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number_entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28dip" />
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/store_id_entry"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="28dip"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then here's the listener code:

```
lv_custom.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        //Log.v("ITEM",lv_custom.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
        c.moveToPosition(position);
        String adr = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ADDRESS));
        String city = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_CITY));
        String name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_NAME));
        String store_id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_STORE_ID));
        String phone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PHONE));
        String zip = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ZIP));
        String state = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_STATE));
        Intent intent=new Intent(DisplayActivity.this,DisplayInfoActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Address: ",adr);
        intent.putExtra("City: ", city);
        intent.putExtra("Zip: ", " " + zip + ", ");
        intent.putExtra("State: ", state);
        intent.putExtra("Name: ", name);
        intent.putExtra("Store ID: ", "Store ID " + store_id);
        intent.putExtra("Phone: ", phone);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Here's the new activity code:

```
public class  DisplayInfoActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list_entry);

        TextView address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address_entry);
        TextView city = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.city_entry);
        TextView zip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.zip_entry);
        TextView state = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.state_entry);
        TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_entry);
        TextView store_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.store_id_entry);
        TextView phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_entry);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        address.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Address: "));
        city.setText(intent.getStringExtra("City: "));
        zip.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Zip: "));
        state.setText(intent.getStringExtra("State: "));
        name.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Name: "));
        store_id.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Store ID: "));
        phone.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Phone: "));
    }
}
```

The problem is that it shows only the address, the city, the zip code, and the state. It does not  show the name, store id and the phone number. What happens with them? Why they are not shown/seen on the new screen?  Actually, before I added more extras, I could see all the extras in my intent. Is there a problem with the number of extras? Thanks for help, if you have an answer for me!

Comment: that's weird, atleast for store-id you should be able to see "Store ID " displayed because that's a value you are sending. Are you saying you are not even seeing that? If you do this: name.setText("some_name"); store_id.setText("some_store_id"); phone.setText("some_phone_num"); what do you see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify adding extras - no need to use extra characters as key:

```
intent.putExtra("Address",adr);
intent.putExtra("City", city);
intent.putExtra("Zip", " " + zip + ", ");
intent.putExtra("State", state);
intent.putExtra("Name", name);
intent.putExtra("StoreID", "Store ID " + store_id);
intent.putExtra("Phone", phone);
```

and correspondingly, in your DisplayInfoActivity:

```
address.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Address"));
city.setText(intent.getStringExtra("City"));
zip.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Zip"));
state.setText(intent.getStringExtra("State"));
name.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Name"));
store_id.setText(intent.getStringExtra("StoreID"));
phone.setText(intent.getStringExtra("Phone"));
```

Next, have you tried printing the extras to logcat, in case your layout is incorrect? Add this below the lines where you retrieve extras:

```
Log.d("MYTAG", "Name: " + intent.getStringExtra("Name"));
```

and see if you can see it in logcat. If yes, maybe your layout is not showing all those TextViews.

Btw, try moving the last 3 TextViews (name, store_id and number) in your layout file INSIDE the second LinearLayout (together with all the other textviews), just to see if they are displayed.

Comment: Yes, the layout was not correct. I had to replace the height of the inner Layout with android:layout_height="74dp", where previously it was android:layout_height="match_parent". So the additional info was out of the screen. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Your inner horizontal LinearLayout's height is set to `match_parent`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Thus, it stretches to the bottom of the screen and leaves no place for your other three TextViews. Therefore it should be set to `wrap_content`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Your layout is wrong

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address_entry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="28dip" /> 
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

...
```

You should have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/address_entry"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="28dip" /> 

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

...
```

Because your second LinearLayout is taking all the remaining screen