# Display intent extras in logcat

Tags: android, debugging, android-intent, logcat, gmail-api

I'm trying to comprehend the intent that sends by the gmail-widget to open messages in the original Gmail-App. If I click on an E-Mail in the widget, I'll get the following Logcat output:

```
09-29 14:42:51.312: I/ActivityManager(1550): START u0 
{act=android.intent.action.VIEW
 dat=content://com.google.android.gm.email.provider/uimessage/87?threadOp=true&appVersion=58454703&folderUri=content://com.google.android.gm.email.provider/uifolder/1 typ=application/gm-email-ls flg=0x1000c000 pkg=com.google.android.gm cmp=com.google.android.gm/.ui.MailActivityGmail (has extras)} from uid 10066 on display 0
```

But I didn't get how to display the extras which got send. If I try to imitate the action I only see the gmail inbox. I'm using this code:

```
Intent defineIntent =new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://com.google.android.gm.email.provider/uimessage/86?threadOp=true&appVersion=58454703&folderUri=content://com.google.android.gm.email.provider/uifolder/1"));
Bundle extra = new Bundle();
extra.putString("exchange_username", "XXX");
extra.putString("email_address", "XXXX");
defineIntent.setType("application/gm-email-ls");
defineIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
defineIntent.setClassName("com.google.android.gm", "com.google.android.gm.ui.MailActivityGmail");


defineIntent.putExtras(extra);

defineIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(defineIntent);
```

After the inbox is shown the gmail app throws an error in logcat:

> 09-29 14:46:01.457: W/Gmail(13334): email_address in bundle is empty

But I've set the email_adress string in my extra-bundle.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10108097/5832311), make the most basic passing of data from one activity to another first before involving other data objects.

For the next issue:

> But I didn't get how to display the extras which got sent.

You can check this [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318089/start-activity-using-intent-with-extra-does-not-show-all-the-extras). You can use the [`Intent.hasExtra(String name)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#hasExtra(java.lang.String)) to check if an extra with `name` was passed in the intent. Also, use [`Intent.getStringExtra(String name)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)) directly on the intent to handle the `NullPointerException` if no extras were passed.

Comment: Yes, sure. But only if the Intent was send to my own application. I can see that Intents got send by other Applications installed in the emulator in my Logcat, but didnt see the extras(just the hint: "Has Extras").